# Hypothetical aplication of rules/restricting rules to a given context?

Tags: evaluation, tensors

I have the code `TensorDimensions[TensorContract[c, {{1, 2}}]]`. It is in normal form. But if I add the rules:

```
Unprotect[TensorDimensions]
TensorDimensions[c] = {4, 4, 5}
```

then the code evaluates to `{5}`.

I was wondering, is there some specific language construct that would give me the result of the evaluation `TensorDimensions[TensorContract[c, {{1, 2}}]]` **if I  were** to add those rules, without actually adding those rules in the global context?

I would like to see what would happen to the expression evaluation **if** the rules were added, but not add the rules. Is this possible? Like a "stronger" version of what `ReplaceAll` does.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use `TensorReduce[]` with assumptions:

```
Assuming[c ∈ Arrays[{4, 4, 5}],
        TensorReduce[TensorDimensions[TensorContract[c, {{1, 2}}]]]]
   {5}
```

Comment: This works for the particular case of `TensorDimensions` , however I'm still wondering if it's possible to have a general construct that operates like I've described in my post. I've tried using contexts with `Begin` and `End`, but it turns out if you're in a context and add rules to a function that's already defined in the global context, the rules "leak out" to the global context. `Block` and `Module` don't seem to work as would be needed also. The 'Unset` function seems like the most helpful for this kind of construct, but it unsets everithing, not just locally added rules.